# When I am running code it is this error how to fix it?

Tags: macos, c++11, visual-studio-code, gcc

[image]

Please help me to resolve this error.

gcc compiler is not working in ventura macOS
. When I am running code it is showing that update your include path. Please help me how gcc will be working in ventura. gcc was properly working in big sir macOS. But after updating my macOS it is not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why post an image of text only stuff, hard to search for the text